# How to Access button present in WPF cell of WPF table

Tags: wpf-controls, wpfdatagrid, coded-ui-tests

I am Testing WPF Application using Coded UI.. My testcase is like verifying whether button is enabled or not. wpf button is present in wpftcell which is in the wpftable.

```
      public void verifyInstall_uninstallButton()
        {
            ResultsPageClasses.ResultsPage Objresultpage = new ResultsPageClasses.ResultsPage();

            WpfButton btninstall = Objresultpage.UISalesforceConnectorVWindow.UIItemTable.UIItemDataItem.UIItemCell.UIInstallButton;
            WpfButton btnunInstall = Objresultpage.UISalesforceConnectorVWindow.UIItemTable.UIItemDataItem.UIItemCell.UIUninstallButton;
            WpfCell cell = Objresultpage.UISalesforceConnectorVWindow.UIItemTable.UIItemDataItem.UIItemCell;
            WpfTable table=Objresultpage.UISalesforceConnectorVWindow.UIItemTable;
            WpfControl dataitem = Objresultpage.UISalesforceConnectorVWindow.UIItemTable.UIItemDataItem;
if(btnunInstall.Enabled)
            {
                Console.Write("pass");
            }}
```

When I run this My test is getting fail following error is displayed

System.ArgumentException: No row was specified as search container for the control. To search for a cell control using 'ColumnIndex', you must specify row as a container element or add 'RowIndex' to the search property of the cell.
Parameter name: SearchProperties

I am Using visula studio premium update 2 2012

Can any help me to solve this

Thanks